# Unable retrieve post from Graph API for a Keyword

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=ATT&type=post

Steps to Reproduce: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=ATT&type=post
Expected Behavior:  Graph search has to retrieve the posts which is relevant to ATT.
Actual Behavior:    Please find below output

- Output

{
   "data": [

]
}

Comment: You may report it as bug, example http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/385073941575300

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried experimenting with a different search term? The following searches work:

- https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=ball&type=post
- https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=raccoon&type=post
- https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=stackoverflow&type=post

So it seems that the issue is with the keyword `ATT` as opposed to the Graph API search syntax you are using.